# Sign magnitude addition of 0 and -0?

Tags: binary

What is the result when 0000+1000 in sign-magnitude representation?

Would it be 0000 or 1000 they seem equally likely to me and there I can't find any information on the internet.

Comment: [This math SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2291450) seems to recommend that you convert the sign-magnitude numbers to two's complement, do the addition using two's complement, and then convert back to sign-magnitude. If you do that, what do you get then?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude in that case it should give 0000. However I have also seen people saying we don't change the sign if the two values are in the same parity. So regarding 1000+1000 the answer again differs.